# Создание приветственного окна

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, dialog

```
import sys, random
from maketmain import *
from arrays import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget



#Класс основного окна
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Исторические личности")
        self.NameOfPerson()
        self.Head()
        self.Nose()
        self.Chin()
#Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопки
        self.ui.checkButton.clicked.connect(self.CheckButton) #Кнопка проверки
        self.ui.nexthead.clicked.connect(self.nexthead) #Кнопка"ГоловаВперёд"
        self.ui.backhead.clicked.connect(self.backhead) #Кнопка"ГоловаНазад"
        self.ui.nextnose.clicked.connect(self.nextnose) #Кнопка"НосВперёд"
        self.ui.backnose.clicked.connect(self.backnose) #Кнопка"НосНазад"
        self.ui.nextchin.clicked.connect(self.nextchin) #Кнопка"ПодбородокВперёд"
        self.ui.backchin.clicked.connect(self.backchin) #Кнопка"ПодбородокНазад"
#Заголовок(Выводится Имя Исторической личности)
    def NameOfPerson(self):
        # Здесь все возможные имена Исторических людей.
        global name
        name = random.choice(namesofperson)
        self.ui.nameofperson.setText(name)
        return
#Блок с Собранием Лба
    def Head(self):
        # Здесь все возможные лбы Исторических людей
        global head
        global index_head
        head = []
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head0.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head1.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head2.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head3.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head4.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head5.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head6.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head7.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head8.png'))
        head.append(QPixmap('images\head\head9.png'))
        global head_check
        head_check = random.choice(head)
        self.ui.head.setPixmap(head_check)
        index_head = head.index(head_check)
        print(index_head)
#Блок с Собиранием Носа
    def Nose(self):
        # Здесь все возможные носы Исторических людей
        global index_nose
        global nose
        nose = []
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose0.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose1.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose2.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose3.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose4.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose5.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose6.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose7.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose8.png'))
        nose.append(QPixmap('images\mnose\mnose9.png'))
        global nose_check
        nose_check = random.choice(nose)
        index_nose = nose.index(nose_check)
        self.ui.nose.setPixmap(nose_check)
        print(index_nose)
#Блок с Собиранием Подбородка
    def Chin(self):
        # Здесь все возможные подбородки Исторических людей
        global index_chin
        global chin
        chin = []
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin0.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin1.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin2.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin3.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin4.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin5.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin6.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin7.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin8.png'))
        chin.append(QPixmap('images\chin\chin9.png'))
        global chin_check
        chin_check = random.choice(chin)
        index_chin = chin.index(chin_check)
        self.ui.chin.setPixmap(chin_check)
        print(index_chin)
# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется
# при нажатии на кнопку
    def CheckButton(self):
        if name == namesofperson[0] and index_head == 0 and index_nose == 0 and index_chin == 0:
            self.ui.result.setText("Правильно")
            self.NameOfPerson()
            self.Head()
            self.Nose()
            self.Chin()
        else:
            self.ui.result.setText("Не правильно. Попробуйте снова.")
#ФункцияКнопки"ВперёдГолова":
    def nexthead(self):
        global index_head
        index_head += 1
        if index_head <= 9:
            self.ui.head.setPixmap(head[index_head])
        else:
            index_head = 9

        print(index_head)
#ФункцияКнопки"НазадГолова"
    def backhead(self):
        global index_head
        index_head -= 1
        if index_head >= 0:
            self.ui.head.setPixmap(head[index_head])
        else:
            index_head = 0
        print(index_head)
#ФункцияКнопки"ВперёдНос"
    def nextnose(self):
        global index_nose
        index_nose += 1
        if index_nose <= 9:
            self.ui.nose.setPixmap(nose[index_nose])
        else:
            index_nose = 9
        print(index_nose)
#ФункцияКнопки"НазадНос"
    def backnose(self):
        global index_nose
        index_nose -= 1
        if index_nose >= 0:
            self.ui.nose.setPixmap(nose[index_nose])
        else:
            index_nose = 0
        print(index_nose)
#ФункцияКнопки"ВперёдПодбородок"
    def nextchin(self):
        global index_chin
        index_chin += 1
        if index_chin <= 9:
            self.ui.chin.setPixmap(chin[index_chin])
        else:
            index_chin = 9
        print(index_chin)
#ФункцияКнопки"НазадПодбородок"
    def backchin(self):
        global index_chin
        index_chin -= 1
        if index_chin >= 0:
            self.ui.chin.setPixmap(chin[index_chin])
        else:
            index_chin = 0
        print(index_chin)



#Вызов
if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())



name = 0
```

У меня есть программа в которой только одно окно при открытии (MainWindow) Я хочу добавить маленькое окошко приветствия в самом начале перед запуском MainWindow. Подскажите, как этом можно реализовать? Желательно код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант для красоты всплывающее окно приветствия

P.s [Более упрощенный вариант](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a152888e7188423149c9ce5462c4274bf4d507bd/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5__WelcomeWidget.py) сделал [@gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class NameClass(QtWidgets.QDialog):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.Tool | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        label.setText("Welcome my app")
        label.setStyleSheet("""QLabel { color : #fff; 
                                       margin-top: 6px;
                                       margin-bottom: 6px;
                                       margin-left: 10px;
                                       margin-right: 10px; 
                                       font-size: 50px;}""")
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(label)

        self.setLayout(lay)
        self.adjustSize()
        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self, b"windowOpacity", self)
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.hide)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.hideAnimation)

    def paintEvent(self, event: QtGui.QPaintEvent):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        rounded_rect = QtCore.QRect()
        rounded_rect.setX(self.rect().x() + 5)
        rounded_rect.setY(self.rect().y() + 5)
        rounded_rect.setWidth(self.rect().width() - 10)
        rounded_rect.setHeight(self.rect().height() - 10)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 180)))
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(rounded_rect, 10, 10)

    def show(self):
        screen_geometry = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry()
        pos = screen_geometry.center() - self.geometry().center()
        self.move(pos)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.0)
        self.animation.setDuration(1500)
        self.animation.setStartValue(0.0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(1.0)
        super().show()
        self.animation.start()
        self.timer.start(3000)

    def hideAnimation(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.animation.setDuration(1500)
        self.animation.setStartValue(1.0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0.0)
        self.animation.start()

    def hide(self):
        if self.windowOpacity() == 0:
            super().hide()
            self.main = Main()
            self.main.show()


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        sld = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        sld.setStyleSheet("""
            QSlider{
                background: #E3DEE2;
            }
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {  
                height: 10px;
                margin: 0px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background: #B0AEB1;
            }
            QSlider::handle:horizontal {
                background: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #E3DEE2;
                width: 17px;
                margin: -5px 0; 
                border-radius: 8px;
            }
            QSlider::sub-page:qlineargradient {
                background: #3B99FC;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
        """)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(sld)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = NameClass()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам за ещё одно спасение и красоту

Comment: Анимация это вещь :) А зачем так сложно `QtWidgets.QWidget.show(self)`? :)

Comment: @gil9red ну к моему сожалению как то так и получается :D p.s.(просто ошибку выдает, вот и костыли появляются)

Comment: Ааа, вы перекрыли стандартный метод, поэтому вызывая `self.show()` вызывали рекурсию. Тогда сделайте так: `super().show()`

Comment: @gil9red согласен так проще)

Comment: Тоже самое и про `QtWidgets.QWidget.hide(self)` ) Кст, мне кажется `NameClass` лучше от QDialog сделать и вызывать в `__main__` -- так проще будет его повторно использовать, да и перестанет от зависеть от класса Main

Comment: Кст, вот способ проще и более qt'шный для получения центра: `pos = screen_geometry.center() - self.geometry().center()` и после `self.move(pos)`. У вас вручную это :)

Comment: Вчера думал как упростить ваш код (мне он показался в некоторых местах излишним) и сделать его более переиспользуемым и вот что получилось: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a152888e7188423149c9ce5462c4274bf4d507bd/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt5__WelcomeWidget.py

Comment: @gil9red хм достаточно компактно интересно. Учту на будущее:)

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать модальный диалог `QMessageBox`. Если нужно его показать *до* появления `MyWin`, то строку с ним переместить до `myapp`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

...

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()

    QMessageBox.information(None, 'Приветствие', 'Это программа для <...>.\nЖелаю приятного использования!')

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

Пример автозакрытия окна с сообщением:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

myapp = MyWin()
myapp.show()

text = 'Это программа для <...>.\nЖелаю приятного использования!'
message_box = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, 'Приветствие', text)

# Через 5 секунд QTimer вызовет message_box.close()
QTimer.singleShot(5000, message_box.close)

message_box.exec()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Если стандарный `QMessageBox` не устраивает, то придется свой диалог от `QDialog`.

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, чтобы оно закрывалось автоматически секунд через 5?

Comment: @МаксимХалин Можно, но нужно будет создавать объект от QMessageBox и через QTimer вызывать его закрытие

Comment: а без кнопки "ОК" это надо делать Qdialog?

Comment: Да, создаете виджет от QDialog, добавляете на него, например QLabel, после создаете объект QDialog, указываете в его label'е текст и вызываете через exec()